# how can i filter and clear other apps cache from my app programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot and see stackoverflow answers related to this but it is concerned with clearing of my own app cache but I want to clear other apps cache.
when you see apps like 360Security,phone Manager in huawei they show how much cache an app stored and clear them based on user's interest so how can I filter and clear other apps' cache (not my own app) ?
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source app.That you can take those ideas.

https://github.com/Frozen-Developers/android-cache-cleaner

Comment: I am new to Android and the code you gave me to see is a little bit complicated can you please filter out and show me the code only to clear cache ?

Comment: @Sura please refer to line 169 and 250 in this file : https://github.com/Frozen-Developers/android-cache-cleaner/blob/master/CacheCleaner/src/main/java/com/frozendevs/cache/cleaner/model/CleanerService.java